# How to increase the amount of cores and heap memory each gridgain node contributes to the cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, gridgain

I am running GridGain nodes on separate VMs each with >=16 GB of RAM. Currently, it appears the default is that each GridGain node instance contributes 1 Core and 2 GB of RAM to the cluster. I will to be able to modify this but looking at GridConfiguration and GridCacheConfiguration I seem to be lost. Ideally, each GridGain node instance would contribute >6 GB of RAM to the cluster.

Searches for on-heap memory in GridGain usually lead me to offheap memory configurations.

Furthermore, I wanted to ask what is the significance of a cache's start size, as noted in the configuration file below:

```
<bean id="cache-template" abstract="true" class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration"> 
        <property name="startSize" value="1000000"/> 
        <property name="preloadMode" value="NONE"/> 
        <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="PRIMARY_SYNC"/>    
        <property name="queryIndexEnabled" value="true"/> 
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `-Xmx` settings for your application startup. If you are using `ggstart.sh` script, then it sets the memory to 1GB, but you can change it by updating the `JVM_OPTS` variable in the script.

As far as cores go, GridGain is multithreaded and each GridGain instance will utilize all available cores, if they are free.